# Ajax call function for each tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I created responsive tabs just using css. But when I try to implement ajax calls, i am bit confused.

I have a few questions:

1. What is the best way to make ajax request for each tab?
2. Is there any shortest way to append response to "tab" div?
3. How can I call ajax on page load for selected tab?
4. After first click on tab, do not need to make ajax call again. I need to cache response, but "`cache:true`" does not work.

Also any other improvements, suggestions and corrections would be helpful.

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdL1z8k6/)

Comment: i would consider not using ajax at all if the content is not going to change you can just store it directly in a javascript variable. than on the clicked tab put in the relevant data for that tab.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I think we can handle cache issue by using variables. But still i am wondering about using ajax cache. And also other questions' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you must use ajax i would run a loop through all the data you need to load do it at once an store the data in a variable (or object in this case)

than the change event will get the id from the tabData which is already populated and you won't need to call the ajax pages again.

now this will solve your cache problem since you won't need it for this scenario

if you want to instant populate the first selected tab when you open the page created an if statement in the ajax success

end result would look something along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //data for the tabs 
    var tabs = {
        1:"tabone",
        2:"tabtwo",
        3:"tabthree"
    }

    //empty object for now will be filled with ajax data
    var tabData = {};

    var activeTabVal=1;
    var activeTabID = $('input[name=tabs]:checked', ".tabs").attr('id');


    for(key in tabs) {
       ajaxCall(key);
    }



    $('.tabs input').on('change', function() {
        var activeTab=$('input[type="radio"]:checked', '.tabs').val();
        var tabElement =  $('input[name=tabs]:checked', ".tabs").attr('id');
        //since we have the data already no need to call ajax here we just get it out of our already loaded data
        var data = tabData[activeTab];
        replaceData(tabElement, data);
    });

    function ajaxCall(key){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+key,
            async: false,
            cache: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                tabData[key] = msg.body;
                 //use this to imediatly populate the selected div fo your second point
                if(key == activeTabVal) {
                    replaceData(tabs[key], tabData[key]);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function replaceData(tabElement, tabData) {
        $('#'+tabElement).next().next().closest('div').append(tabData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @herriekrekel. I have one more question. What if I don't want load all data on load, just need to call when I click tab. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: yeay you should instead of looping through the ajaxCalls you can call ajaxCall in the change like you had yourself. Than make an if(tabsData[key] !== 'undefined') around the ajax call so you won't need to call it a second time when the data us already set than call the replaceData function to set it in the element

Answer (score 1):

1. I would instead of calling it on change I would call it on tab button clicked
2. Give your tab a data-id and the corresponding container div the same data-id, then when you append you can do something like `$('.tab-container[data-id='+$(this).attr('data-id')+']').append('The content');`
3. If you bind it to click you can simply run `$('.tab-button .active').trigger('click');`
4. If I were you I would store the data into the data portion of the container div and retrieve it again when they click on it again. So you just check if it was set, if not then do ajax call, if it was just pluck it out and display it. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/